# update a uipicker

Tags: iphone, uipicker

I have two columns, in the uipicker. When I select something from the first column, I want the options to change on the other column.

Source code anyone?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: check out this stackoverflow answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311552/dependent-uipickerview

Answer (score 0):

Check out the book 'Iphone 4 development' from Apress, at chapter 7 there is made a dependent picker, the one that you want to make (it's called a dependent uipickerview).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this -

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {

        //Here First Part of the Pickerview is represented using 0.
        // dependentPicker is the Pickerview outlet

        [dependentPicker selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES];
        [dependentPicker reloadComponent:1];
    }
    else
    {
        [dependentPicker selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [dependentPicker reloadComponent:1];
    }
}
```