# how to disable a one component in uipickerview until another component is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I m creating a picker view with 2 components.first component has countries names and second has their cities.
Now my requirement is that the user can select second component only if first component is selected until then second component is in disable state.

Note: The main problem is when the user selected a country  and immediately selected city before the second component is reloaded it gives an exception

Comment: use dependent pickerView, Check the [Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077470/question-regarding-implementation-of-multi-component-dependent-uipickerview?lq=1

Comment: but i want to disable the second component until first is selected(i.e. when picker view comes into picture second must be in disabled state and must be enabled only when first component is selected).

Answer (score 0):

Use Dependent pickerView, it will help you in this case.